# How to refer to component object within intercept/arrow function?

Tags: angular, this, arrow-functions, intercept

Here's my code:

```js
export class NetworkInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    // ...

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        // ...
      }),
      tap({
        next(res) {},
        error(error) {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/signin'));
            }
          }
        },
        complete() {},
      })
    );
  }
}
```

But can't use

```
this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/signin'))
```

within `intercept`, since `this` doesn't refers to component's object.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to navigate to a route using the router service, on a 401 error, you don't need to use ngZone. [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) is a service we use when bringing into angular events from the outside of angular's scope/zone.

What you need is to use [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/catchError) in a more simplistic way, you will be set for the win with something like the following:

```js
export class NetworkInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    // ...
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/signin');
        }
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an arrow functino for your tap payload

```js
tap({
  next: () => {...},
  error: () => {...},
  complete: () => {...},
})
```

**EDIT** personal opinion, but you should rather use `catchError` operator, which seems more suited in your case.

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring a local variable for the router instance inside the intercept function. And then you use that variable in your code.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    // ...
    const interceptorRouter = this.router;
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            // ...
        }),
        tap({
            next(res) { },
            error(error) {
                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (error.status === 401) {
                        this.ngZone.run(() => interceptorRouter.navigateByUrl('/account/signin'));
                    }
                }
            },
            complete() { }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: not very elegant as solution. the router reference should be one....

Comment: Sadly, elegance is not always on same side as functionality.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very simple approach that I had in a past application, I don't know if you find that elegant enough:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router, @Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error?.status === 401) {
          logout(this.window, this.router);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

You can inject `NgZone` if the same with `Window` & `Router`.

Comment: Not sure about your code. this.router should be the same as mine. Why it should work? the problem is within tap function, which doesn't reckon "this"

Comment: I create an example in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-interceptor-theayt?file=app/http.interceptor.ts